# tableGrob alignment and spacing in Rmarkdown/knitr-HTML document

Tags: r, html-table, knitr, r-markdown, gridextra

I have the following issues when using the nice feature `tableGrob()` from `gridExtra` package to plot a table in an html document produced by Rmarkdown and `knitr`.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(datasets)
library(dplyr)
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$carb)
carb.mpg <- mtcars %>%
            select(carb,mpg) %>%
            group_by(carb)   %>%
            summarise_each(funs(sum(.,na.rm=TRUE)),-carb) %>%
            arrange(desc(mpg))
##plot the table
tab <- tableGrob(carb.mpg, cols=c("carb","mpg"), 
              theme=ttheme_minimal())
grid.arrange(tab, top=textGrob("Cars MPG per CARB",gp=gpar(fontsize=16,font=1)) )
```

For `knitr` general chunk options:

```
title: "Test with cars"
output: 
html_document:
keep_md: true
```

`{r setoptions, echo=FALSE}
   library(knitr)
   opts_chunk$set(message=FALSE,warning=FALSE)`

The issue as can been seen from the attached snapshot is the *huge space*[image] between the table and its title and legend. It would be also nice if I could left-align the table in the document.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tweaking, I found that the position of the table can be controlled using `viewport` (x and y); width/height seem obsolete.

```
#plot the table
 tab <- tableGrob(carb.mpg, cols=c("carb","mpg"), 
          theme=ttheme_minimal())
 grid.newpage()
 vp  <- viewport(width=0.90,height=0.90,x=0.10,y=0.80,clip="on")
 pushViewport(vp)
 grid.draw(tab)
```

This solves the problem only partially: the *huge* vertical space is still there.[image]

Perhaps this gives some direction to resolving the issue?

**EDIT**: one way that worked for me to control the white spaces/margins was to reduce the figure size parameters in `knitr` chunk options, i.e.,

`{r plot mpg cars, fig.height=value, fig.width=value}`

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
tg <- textGrob("Cars MPG per CARB", gp=gpar(fontsize=16,font=1))
grid.arrange(tg, tab, heights=unit.c(grobHeight(tg), sum(tab$heights)),
             vp=viewport(x=unit(0,"npc") + 
                            0.5*unit.pmax(grobWidth(tg), 
                                          sum(tab$widths))))
```

[image]

Comment: @ baptiste, thanks for the feedback. I tested your suggestion; it doesn't appear to solve the issue. I am posting perhaps a beginning of the answer.

Comment: the table has a fixed size that corresponds to the text labels inside, as opposed to, say, ggplot graph, which automatically extend to fill the viewport. If you don't want this white space, you should probably adjust the figure size; you can query it from the table grob (in a previous chunk) with `convertUnits(sum(table$heights), "in", valueOnly=TRUE)`

Comment: @ baptiste: indeed, I could reduce the margins via the "figure" size parameters in `knitr` r code chunk options. Also, in gridExtra *V# 0.9.1*, it was possible to set `tableGrob(..., show.vlines = TRUE)` for vertical line. How to do that now with nested `theme=ttheme_minimal(...)`?